# The precise meaning of "to have something more to do with somebody/something"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, comparatives, comparisons

There are other questions about the meaning of "to have something to do with somebody/something". My question here is about "to have something **more** to do with somebody/something". There is a sense of comparison in this phrase as in the following sentence:

> The truth about genealogy is that, although you might believe it has something to do with history, it actually has something more to do with geography. [Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=QBaQYwCZ2DMC&pg=PA228&lpg=PA228&dq=%22has%20something%20more%20to%20do%20with%22&source=bl&ots=HHe0m-8Jmz&sig=3JNyOGLyGAZcgH_nTdd5dAUdHpY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7uuikqPXUAhWsJJoKHV5qArEQ6AEIMDAD)

In the above sentence comparison follows the following pattern:

> A has something to do with X, but it has something more to do with Y.

That much is clear. But my question is whether it also may mean comparison in the following pattern:

> A has something to do with X, but B has something more to do with X.

Or otherwise put:

> Compared to A, B has something more to do with X.

Comment: The link between B and X is more significant than A to X.

Comment: @marcellothearcane So, yes?

Comment: Yes, I think so...

Comment: Please [edit] this to use full words instead of unclear abbreviations like "sb/sth"

Answer (score -1):

Your interpretation of the writer's intent is correct, but his grammar is dubious. Whereas *something* denotes a single undefined thing, it is countable and singular, and cannot not be modified by *more*. You can, however, say *something else*, but it would mean "some other thing", which is not the meaning intended. In order to make this sentence good English, omit the second instance of *something*:

> The truth about genealogy is that, although you might believe it has something to do with history, it actually has more to do with geography.

By omission of the noun, the phrase *to have to do* lets the author imply an uncountable or plural object, such as *things*:

> Genealogy has more *things* to do with geography than with history.

**EDIT:** Another fault in the original sentence is that its author sets the following two statements in opposition:

1. genealogy has something to do with history and
2. genealogy has more to do with geography,

whereas they not contradict each other. In order to justify *although*, the contrast must be more evident , e.g.:

> Although you might believe that geology relies primarily on history, its reliance on geography is much stronger.

Comment: But my question was not about the first meaning of the comparison. I asked if the second meaning of it is acceptable.

Comment: Since I consider *something more* ungrammatical, I cannot advise you about its acceptable meaning. I am certain, however, that the meaning intended by the writer is that genealogy has more to do with geography than with history. In other words, knowledge of geography is more important for a genealogist than that of history.

Comment: I understand that much. The question is not that. The question is whether "have something more to do with" might have the second meaning too?

Comment: Specify the correspondence between *X*, *A*, and *B* in your second pattern to *genealogy*, *history*, and *geography*.